# Rails - Problems using Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I'm having problems trying to edit a model. I always end up getting as error

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

I'm using in the view:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
```

and on the controller:

```
 def edit
@title = "Edit Book"
 end

def update
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
  flash[:success] = "Book Updated"
  redirect_to @book
else
  @title = "Edit Book"
  render 'edit_book_path(@book)'
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the @book variable in the 'edit' action. As you can see from your view:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
```

the @book variable is used for rendering the form. Thus:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

is needed in edit method.